# How to handle a connection of a second monitor in a KDE5 plasmoid?

Tags: c++, qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

Essentially, the question is asked in the subj. I have some plasmoid and I need to handle the event when a secondary screen appeared in the system.

Answer (score 1):

If Plasma itself doesn't have API for that specific type of event, then the C++ part of your plugin should be able to get access to the `QGuiApplication` of the Plasma process and connect a slot to its `screenAdded(QScreen*)` signal.